# replace newline with end of line in sed

Tags: awk, sed

what is the difference between the following

```
cat script | sed -n ';s/\W|\W/\n/g; s/\W>\W/\n/g;p' | sed -n 's/\W/\n/1;p ' | sed -n  'x;n;x;p'

cat script | sed -n -e ';s/\W|\W/\n/g; s/\W>\W/\n/g;p' -e 's/\W/\n/1;p '  -e  'x;n;x;p'
```

using ;l; there is apparent difference in treating \n, and end of line $, sed doesn't treat streams delimited by \n as different lines, but each line ends with it's original end of line. is there a way to insert endofline without pipelining?

sample script

```
prog1 arg1 | prog2 opt1
prog3 arg3 > filename
```

sample output

```
prog1
prog2
prog3
filename
```

script support redirection(>), and pipelining(|), and limited executables.
output is executable name, or redirection file.

Comment: Could you please post samples of input and expected output in your post too, we will get a better picture of your question.

Comment: If you increase the number of lines (`s/\W|\W/\n/g`) with sed, then you need several sed with pipes instead of one sed with the option `-e`.

Comment: sure, but my question is about is there alternative?

Comment: i mean, how to insert end of line, s/something/endofline/ doesn't work with endofline being $, \$

Comment: What do you mean by `insert end of line`? `$` is the end of string (often `line` for sed) indicator in a regexp, and `\n` (or sometimes `\r\n`) is the usual end of line indicator for text files. Are you trying to match on end of line (`$`) or insert end of line (`\n`)? Whatever those scripts are doing is a horrible mess, completely inappropriate for `sed`. If you provide sample input and expected output we can show you how to do whatever it is you're trying to do with a clear, simple script (that certainly will not involve sed!).

Comment: edited, with samples